# Why is my C program skipping over if statements?

Tags: c

I am a new coder and have no idea what I am doing please help!

The code is reading and taking inputs just fine until it reaches the scanf(" %c", &i);then it skips to the Amount print seemingly ignoring my if statements.Is there somthing wrong with my use of scanF?

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
printf("BANK ACCOUNT PROGRAM!\n--------------------\n");
char W,F,A,i,D; 
int t=1;
double b,d;

while (t=1){
    printf("Enter the old balance:\n");
    scanf(" %lf", &b);
    printf(" %lf", b);
    if(b>=0)
        {
    printf("Enter the transactions now!\n Enter an F for the transaction type when you are finished.\n");

    printf("Transaction Type (D=deposit, W=withdrawal, F=finished):\n");
    scanf(" %c", &i);
    if(i=F){
        printf("Your ending balance is");
        printf(" %lf", b);
        printf("\n Program is ending!");

        return 0;
        }
    if(i=W){
        printf("Amount:");
        scanf(" %f", &d);
        b= b-d;
        printf(" %f",b);}
    }
    if(b<0);
        {
            printf("The balance must be maintained above zero!\n");

    }


    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to learn the difference between *assignment* `=` and *equivalence comparison* `==` . Every comparison in this code appears to be wrong (and completely legal as-written due to how C supports evaluation of expressions, including assignment expressions). I'm amazed your compiler wasn't barking warnings.

Comment: Thank you! I am sorta going at this on my own with no help so I appreciate the support!

Comment: `%c` reads the next character after the previous scanf, which could be whitespace. Its usually better to read whole lines when getting user input.

Comment: @stark in `scanf(" %c", &i);` the space before `%c` instructs `scanf` to ignore leading whitespace. In all the other calls to `scanf` here that space is unnecessary, because for those format specifiers leading whitespace is filtered anyway. It can still be better to read a whole line though.

Comment: You need a proper compiler that produces warnings for these kinds of mistakes and consider every warning as an error

Comment: Are there any compilers you would recommend? I am using GNU GCC.

Answer (score 2):

Because your comparison is wrong

```
if(i=F){  // this is assignment, not comparison
```

should be

```
if(i=='F'){  // note also it's comparison to character 'F'
```

Comment: You should develop an eye for these as this will bite you hard, again and again, until you can spot the difference at a glance. A single `=` in side an `if` should be alarming.

Comment: I started this week so this is good info to know! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to wrong comparison operators, your way of comparing two chars is also wrong. If you want to check whether the input char `i` equals to `'F'` , you should initialize the char variable `F` with character `'F'`, otherwise it would be just unintialized variable and comparison with that variable would be wrong.

You should add these lines just after you initialize `F` and `W`.

```
F = 'F';
W = 'W';
```

By the way, you can use another variable names like,

```
char var1 = 'F';
char var2 = 'W';
```

Comment: Good to know! Thanks!

Comment: @DanielThoman also you never change the value of `t` apart from the incorrect `while(t=1)` so the loop won't end.